# Swift: Limiting Pinch to not go smaller then original and limit Zoom to no more then 3X

Tags: swift, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I would like to place some limits on Pinching an image. The user should not be able to go smaller then the original image, and no more then 3X the original image. Tried a few things, but have not found a solution. Any help appreciated.

```
// Pinch gesture handler
func pinchHandler(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
recognizer.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view!.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
recognizer.scale = 1
}
```

Comment: What are some of the things you tried?

Comment: Capturing the scale value and adjusting image size based on that. I'm visualizing the view as a balloon. it needs to be wrapped in a ScrollView to access scale as related to zoom end points.